# Large common blocks with address sanitizer in 32-bit mode

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, 32-bit, address-sanitizer

I'm having a problem with legacy Fortran code that can be reduced to this sample:

```
program main
implicit none
write(6,*) 'Hello!'
end program main

subroutine bigdata()
implicit none
!real*8 AA(50292712)
real*8 AA(50292713)
common /big_common/ AA
end subroutine
```

Note that the subroutine is never called from the program. Compiling and running this in a 64-bit machine, gives me:

```
$ gfortran -fsanitize=address main.f ; ./a.out
 Hello!

$ gfortran -m32 main.f ; ./a.out
 Hello!

$ gfortran -m32 -fsanitize=address main.f ; ./a.out                                                                                                               
==32656== Shadow memory range interleaves with an existing memory mapping. ASan cannot proceed correctly. ABORTING.
==32656== Process memory map follows:
        0x08048000-0x08049000   /home/username/a.out
        0x08049000-0x0804a000   /home/username/a.out
        0x0804a000-0x0804b000   /home/username/a.out
        0x0804b000-0x1ffff000
        0xf5d77000-0xf5d78000
        0xf5d78000-0xf5dbc000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
        0xf5dbc000-0xf5dbd000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
        0xf5dbd000-0xf5dbe000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
        0xf5dbe000-0xf5dbf000
        0xf5dbf000-0xf5e38000   /usr/lib32/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
        0xf5e38000-0xf5e39000   /usr/lib32/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
        0xf5e39000-0xf5e3a000   /usr/lib32/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
        0xf5e3a000-0xf5e56000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        0xf5e56000-0xf5e57000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        0xf5e57000-0xf5e5a000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
        0xf5e5a000-0xf5e5b000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
        0xf5e5b000-0xf5e5c000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
        0xf5e5c000-0xf5e74000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
        0xf5e74000-0xf5e75000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
        0xf5e75000-0xf5e76000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
        0xf5e76000-0xf5e78000
        0xf5e78000-0xf6020000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
        0xf6020000-0xf6022000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
        0xf6022000-0xf6023000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
        0xf6023000-0xf6027000
        0xf6027000-0xf6123000   /usr/lib32/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
        0xf6123000-0xf6124000   /usr/lib32/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
        0xf6124000-0xf6125000   /usr/lib32/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
        0xf6125000-0xf6151000   /usr/lib32/libasan.so.0.0.0
        0xf6151000-0xf6152000   /usr/lib32/libasan.so.0.0.0
        0xf6152000-0xf6153000   /usr/lib32/libasan.so.0.0.0
        0xf6153000-0xf7705000
        0xf7731000-0xf773b000
        0xf773b000-0xf773c000   [vdso]
        0xf773c000-0xf775c000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
        0xf775c000-0xf775d000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
        0xf775d000-0xf775e000   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
        0xff80a000-0xff82c000   [stack]
==32656== End of process memory map.
```

gfortran version:

```
$ gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
```

Reducing the size of `AA` by 1 (in my test) gets rid of the problem. The limiting size may be different in different systems or situations.

As far as I can see, the size of the common block is nowhere near 2GB, where I'd expect `-m32` to have problems. Is this a limitation of the address sanitizer? Any command line or runtime trick I could use to work around the issue?

EDIT: It probably has nothing to do with common blocks, but with the fact that arrays in common blocks are allocated even if they are never used. This causes the same problem:

```
      program main
      implicit none
*     real*8, allocatable :: AA(:)
*     !allocate(AA(378272768))
*     allocate(AA(378272769))
      !real*8 AA(50292702)
      real*8 AA(50292705)
      AA(1)=1.0d0
      write(6,*) 'Hello!'
      end program main
```

Note that the limit with an allocatable array is almost 8 times larger than with an static array.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781713/what-is-the-biggest-array-size-for-double-precision-in-fortran-90 .  Was the legacy system 32-bit or was it 36/48/60 bit?

Comment: @cup The code work seems to be working in 32-bit and 64-bit systems (though it's not much tested). As far as I know it was written for 32 or 64 bits. It's only when adding the address sanitizer in 32 bits that the problem shows up.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a limitation of the address sanitizer?

Indeed, on 32-bit Linux Asan needs free area at 0x1ffff000-0x37ffffff for it's shadow memory (see [source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/asan/asan_mapping.h) for other platform ranges). This probably conflicts with the large common arrays in your program.

> Any command line or runtime trick I could use to work around the issue?

The address is unfortunately hard-coded in compiler and runtime library (for performance reasons) so I'm not sure you can fix this without changing your code (e.g. by dynamically allocating the arrays?). Or you can just stick with 64-bit version of the code for Asan testing (chance of conflicts is much lower there).

As a side note - it's recommended to not use common arrays with Asan (see [FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)) because this will prevent detection of buffer overflows in them (don't ask). You can disable them with -fno-common.